# How can i reset my status points? (Strength, Vitality, Focus, etc...)

Tags: fantasy-life

There is no way you can succeed with a hybrid character in Fantasy Life. Unfortunately I realized this too late. Is there any place where i can reset my status points so I can have full power with a Mage or a Paladin? If so, where is it and when do i have access to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you reach level 35 and complete the story, you will have access to the Great Library in the desert town. At night, there should be a talking book NPC, whom you can give a certain amount of money (I think 30k?) to reset your attribute points

Comment: What!!!!! Now I need to finish the story apparently.